# Mysqli real_escape_string validation not working, after putting database connection in a separate file

Tags: php, mysqli

I did have this working ok until I changed my connection details to be in a separate file.
`db_connection.php`
in there I have

```
class db_connection extends \mysqli
{
    function connection(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
    }
}
```

In my `register.php` I have the `require_once ('db_connection.php');`

Inside I have

```
require_once ('db_connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['signup-button'])) { //check if form was submitted
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $mysqli = new db_connection;
    $mysqli->connection();

   $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
   $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string(): invalid object or resource db_connection
```

Comment: It appears that you are sublcassing `mysqli` and then instantiating it as well, passing the value to a function-local variable named `$mysqli` which is thrown away once it goes out of scope for the funciton. Do you really want to subclass `mysql` in the first place?

Comment: when you say subclassing... do you mean how it's extended in the db_connection file? That was an automatic fix I selected.

Comment: Why are you even using real_escape_string anyway? It's essentially obsolete. Use prepared statements and parameters to build your queries instead. It's far less messy and you get better protection against SQL injection and syntax issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little confusing what you are actually trying to ultimately accomplish. At first glance, this feels like a case "trying to solve a problem using OOP just for the sake of using OOP". (*I apologize if that is offensive, I've just seen similar things like this before.*)

First off, using `extend` on any class should only ever be done if you have a specific reason to do so, for instance if you want to add a method, or get access to a *specific* bit of functionality.

Second, extending `mysqli` or any of the database classes, although technically valid, rarely has a legitimate case.

What I think you want is something like this:

```php
class db_connection
{
    private ?mysqli $dbh = null;

    function connection(): mysqli
    {
        if (!$this->dbh) {
            $this->dbh = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
        }

        return $this->dbh;
    }
}

$mysqli = (new db_connection)->connection();
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
```

You'll see that I'm creating a class property called `dbh` (the name can be anything, that is just a common one), and using your method to instantiate it if it doesn't exist, and then returning it.

There is zero advantage in doing this than over regular procedural code, I will note. It isn't right or wrong, it just doesn't help. All of that boilerplate `class` stuff is identical to these three lines:

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
```

The one advantage of the class, I'll note, is that you could store the mysqli as a static property which essentially guarantees it is instantiated only once, however that's the same as creating a global variable along with possibly a helper function.